# Error when installing Lync Server, "Installing OcsCore.msi(Feature_LocalMgmtStore)...failure code 1603"

Tags: lync

Im battling to install Lync Server in a test environment and are at the "Install Local Configuration Store" step. The prerequisites seems alright but bombs when installing the OcsCore.msi

```
...
Checking prerequisite SqlNativeClient...prerequisite satisfied.
Checking prerequisite SqlBackcompat...prerequisite satisfied.
Checking prerequisite UcmaRedist...prerequisite satisfied.
Installing OcsCore.msi(Feature_LocalMgmtStore)...failure code 1603
Error returned while installing OcsCore.msi(Feature_LocalMgmtStore), code 1603. Please consult log at C:\Users\Administrator.HAWC\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Add-OcsCore.msi-Feature_LocalMgmtStore-[2012_07_08][12_00_27].log
```

The logfile doesn't really help me either, this is the end of it

```
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = Windows User
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\9525f.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Lync Server\Deployment\cache\4.0.7577.0\setup\OcsCore.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSERVICE = NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_NETWORKSERVICE = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS = BUILTIN\Administrators
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS = BUILTIN\Users
Property(S): WIX_ACCOUNT_GUESTS = BUILTIN\Guests
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Lync Server\Deployment\cache\4.0.7577.0\setup\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {9521B708-9D80-46A3-9E58-A74ACF4E343E}
=== Logging stopped: 2012-07-08  12:01:46 ===
MSI (s) (98:F8) [12:01:46:354]: Note: 1: 1729 
MSI (s) (98:F8) [12:01:46:354]: Product: Microsoft Lync Server 2010, Core Components -- Configuration failed.

MSI (s) (98:F8) [12:01:46:354]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Microsoft Lync Server 2010, Core Components. 
Product Version: 4.0.7577.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Reconfiguration success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (98:F8) [12:01:46:356]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (98:F8) [12:01:46:356]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:362]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:362]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:363]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:363]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:363]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:364]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:364]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:364]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:364]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (s) (98:84) [12:01:46:373]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (98:D4) [12:01:46:373]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (20:64) [12:01:46:379]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (20:64) [12:01:46:380]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2012-07-08  12:01:46 ===
```

Any advice where to start in this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to some errors in the authentication towards the SQLService instance. Did resolve by reinstalling both lync and sqlserver!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Lync 2013 server standard. There I needed to reinstall the Lync environment from scratch. But I wanted to use the same servers name and IP-addresses.

I removed the "dead" SID:s for the local RTC* groups on the server. Took it out of the domain, and rejoined it again.